# Jquery, Ajax (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, google-chrome, firefox

I'm getting `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` after i reload my page and execute the script first time, after that it works just fine. Any ideas why?

I won't post the whole script of my python and jquery because it will be too long(~1200 lines combined), rather I will post the parts that are responsible for the request to happen.

Python:

```
class testHTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost')
        self.end_headers()
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        parsed_q = urlparse(self.path)
        parsed_b = urlparse(body.decode("utf-8"))
        search_info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed_q.query)
        user_info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed_b.path)
        luk = ''.join(search_info['search'])
        wer = ''.join(search_info['parde'])
        user_id = ''.join(user_info['user'])
        self.wfile.write(bytes(where_to(luk, wer, user_id), "utf8"))
        return

    def do_GET(self):
        print ("get request...")
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.end_headers()
        message = "Nothing to see here."
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
        return
```

Jquery or Ajax:

```
else{
    $(".peenum").html("");
    $(".cont_row").html("");
    $('.progress-bar').css({"width": "0%"})
    var dat = Cookies.get()
    $(".where").each(function(){
        var url = 'http://localhost:8081/?search='+$("#enter_look_for").val()+'&parde='+$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
                method: "POST",
                data: dat,
                success: pajiehali
        });
    });
}
```

If this information isn't enough feel free to ask, I'll post all of my code if that's what it takes to figure it out.

Comment: possibility is that at first time your request takes more time than afterward. you could increase the timeout time for the ajax call by setting timeout: 20000 and check if it works

Comment: Yea, I was just thinking about that too, tried it as well. It seems that it doesn't even connect to the server, nothing shows up on the console...

Comment: It act's as if the server wasn't on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I would like to fill you guys in, hoping that I could get some answers, because I'm really clueless here. This only **happens on Chrome**, and **if you do a request right after the page refresh**. If you **wait a bit** after refreshing **the page** it **works fine**. I **tried** it on **Firefox** and it **worked** like it was supposed to refreshing the page or not. At this point **I'm suspecting** that i found a some kind of **Chrome bug**(that's unlikely), **or** my extensions or **something else** is interfering.

**Turn**ing **AdBlock off** helped.